# How to extract an archive using terraform

Tags: terraform, archive

I am trying to deploy a website on azure storage. For that I need to

- download the files from artifactory as tar.gz or zip file
- extract the archive
- upload files as blobs to the storage account

I can do every step but extracting the archive. Can somebody tell me how to extract an zip or tarball archive using terraform?

Comment: have you considered `remote-exec` provisioner?

Comment: I hoped there would be a more elegant way...

Answer (score 1):

you might use `null_resource` with the `provisioner "local-exec"` inside to do so. It might be any command line or simple bash script wrapper.
https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/resources/provisioners/local-exec.html

```
resource "null_resource" "extract_my_tgz" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "tar xzf my_file.tgz"
  }
}
```

there same you might use for `zip` files as well.

```
resource "null_resource" "extract_my_zip" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "unzip my_file.zip"
  }
}
```